# Gulp --production - Uncaught ReferenceError: f is not defined - socket.io.min.js

Tags: laravel, gulp, production

Application is a Laravel PHP application.

When using `gulp` the application works fine but when running `gulp --production` I get this js error `Uncaught ReferenceError: f is not defined`

The line in the js file is `f.exports=e,a(e,o),e.prototype.name="websocket"` - which is from the `socket.io-client/socket.io.min.js` file.

Looks like the js packer is corrupting something...

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error by using the raw `socket.io.js` file instead of the minified `socket.io.min.js`.

FYI - if you get a similar error with other JS libraries try using the non-minified version.